# Win8 JS displaying progress bar after button click

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous

I have problem which is giving me a headache for last 3 days. 
Im trying to bind my button to function handler which will firstly show progress bar and then do some work. here is code :

```
 ready: function (element, options) {

        // SelectBox && Preview Button

        id("selectBtn").addEventListener("click", this.fireAsynchronousEvent.bind(this));
```

Then fireAsynchronousEvent function :

```
       fireAsynchronousEvent: function () {
        setProgress().
            then(function () {
                selectHandler();
            }).done();
    },
```

setProgress function :

```
 function setProgress() {
    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete) {
        divProgress.appendChild(progress);
        complete();
    })
}
```

and  select Handler :

```
    function selectHandler() {


        if (selectedFilter == "sepia") {
            document.getElementById('pageTitle').innerHTML = "selected:" + selectedFilter;
            sepia();

        }
```

What this code do is after I click button it hangs up a liitle and then progress bar shows with applied sepia to the canvas... :/ I want firstly display progress and then when function is over display picture and remove progress.